# HTTP Header with Location doesn't ID to the URL

Tags: php, header, location

I have a problem using a "header location", below is the code:

```
case 'update':
        updateUser($_GET['ticket_id']);
        header('Location: ../ticket/listOfTicket.php?ticket_id='.$_GET['ticket_id'].'');
        exit;
        break;
```

I'm using `case` because want to I update into a database. The problem here I believe is:

```
header('Location: ../ticket/listOfTicket.php?ticket_id='.$_GET['ticket_id'].'');
```

I don't know where to put the quote `'` and `"`. It will outputted in the URL like this:

```
http://localhost/ticket/listOfTicket.php?ticket_id=
```

It didn't display the ticket_id. Why?

Comment: also you have to check if exist and if it is numeric that $_GET value `if (isset($_GET['ticket_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['ticket_id']))`

Answer (score 1):

You should **always** sanitize your user input. I could easily pass something you're not expecting to $_GET['ticket_id']. Assuming ticket_id is an integer, this works for me when I access the page and set ticket_id to some value.

```
header( 'Location: ../ticket/listOfTicket.php?ticket_id=' . intval( $_GET['ticket_id']));
exit;
```